# What is this transistor?

Tags: transistors, identification

I'm trying to find a replacement part for this component. My knowledge of electronics is rudimentary at best and I'm struggling to find this component just by the text.

It looks like ST D1N B60 C027, but I can't find a replacement online.

[image]

Comment: From the findings in the answers below, you have the Vds voltage and Rdson. Aim for same or higher voltage rating and same or lower Rdson.

Comment: If your knowledge of electronics is rudimentary, how sure can you be  that it needs replacement?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it is an STMicroelectronics [STD1NB60](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/24038/STMICROELECTRONICS/STD1NB60.html) n-channel, 600 V, 1 A MOSFET with an R<sub>DS(on)</sub> of about 8 Ω.

Supplier sites say this STD1NB60 is obsolete, but if you can't buy one anymore you should be able to find one with similar specs; maybe the [STD1NK60](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/std1nk60-1.pdf) is a direct replacement (I haven't checked).

Answer (score 3):

It's a STD1NB60 N-channel 600V 1A PowerMesh MOSFET, made by STMicroelectronics.